# Does Loopback supports proxied authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, loopbackjs, proxy-authentication

I am creating an API in NodeJS using IBM's Loopback (3.x) framework. Loopback seems to handle classic authentication methods (vs database). In my case, we are using a proxied authentication header (from a 3rd party software) with the username and other data from the verified user.

Is it possible to configure Loopback to "trust" requests that contain a specific header with the user information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure loopback to "trust" anything it wants with [dynamic roles](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles).

```
Role.registerResolver('somebodyitrust', function(role, context, cb) { 
    const  iTrustYou = true;
    return cb(null, iTrustYou);
  });
```

But you're going to have to verify that the information is correct, and so you're probably going to have to use a database and access tokens, and so you're back to square one.  Unless you're using [openauth](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/OAuth-2.0.html).

If you do go ahead trying to authorize by fields in the header you'll need to get the request context, which means you'll have to configure [loopback-context](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-context).